# BB86 bottom bracket with BB386 crankset?

Tags: bottom-bracket, compatibility

[image]

This is the markings on my bottom bracket. Will it fit BB386 crankset like the FSA Powerbox?

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/fsa-powerbox-alloy-road-abs-chainset/?curr=SEK&dest=14&prevDestCountryId=14

Thanks!

Comment: A quote from this [guide](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/): "The BB386 EVO cranks are compatible with almost every BB shell standard (BSA, BB30, PF30, BB86)," says Jason Miles of FSA. "We currently make bottom brackets and adaptors for BSA, BB30, and PF30 frames and *are working on BB86 bottom brackets*.  So look for a proper adapter.

Comment: @Grigory Rechistov That's a good answer. You should post it as such instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good [guide](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/) on existing bottom brackets standards.

An excerpt from it: "The BB386 EVO cranks are compatible with almost every BB shell standard (BSA, BB30, PF30, BB86)," says Jason Miles of FSA. "We currently make bottom brackets and adaptors for BSA, BB30, and PF30 frames and are working on BB86 bottom brackets.

So look for a proper adapter. It seems that [this](https://www.bike24.com/p2114179.html) is what your are looking for. Note that you will need a bike shop's help with installing it as it requires to press away the existing BB and press in the new one.